# WCF Webservice does not fill komplex Type send by Soap Lite

Tags: c#, perl, web-services, wcf, soap

I try to send a complex Datatype from Perl to .NET WCF.
Simple Types work fine.

WCF Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]

public interface IWebservice
{
    [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)] 
    [OperationContract]
    void PutColledtedData(ServerInfoCollection Serverdata);
}
```

Class For DataType

```
[DataContract (Name="ServerInfoCollection")]
public class ServerInfoCollection
{

    [DataMember]
    public string OperatingSystem { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string OS_Version { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string OS_Architecture { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string OS_ServicePack { get; set; }

    private long pysicalMem = 0;
    [DataMember]
    public long PysicalMemory
    {
        get { return pysicalMem; }
        set { pysicalMem = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public List<FileSystem> Filesystems { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Interface> Interfaces { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public ServerInfoCollection()
    {
        Filesystems = new List<FileSystem>();
        Interfaces = new List<Interface>();
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Hostname { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string WindowsDomain { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string WindowsDomainRole { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime InstallDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int LogicalProcessors { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int PhysicalProcessors { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IPAddress MonitoringIP { get; set; }
}
```

Soap Envenlove Send to Server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Body>
<PutColledtedData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <Serverdata>
    <OperatingSystem />

    <OS_Version>13.1 (Bottle)</OS_Version>

    <OS_Architecture>x86_64</OS_Architecture>

    <OS_ServicePack>13.1</OS_ServicePack>

    <PysicalMemory>6272438272</PysicalMemory>

    <Manufacturer>VMWare</Manufacturer>

    <Model />

    <Hostname>myServerName</Hostname>

    <Alias>myServerName</Alias>

    <WindowsDomain />

    <WindowsDomainRole />

    <InstallDate>Thu Nov 27 12:21:33 2014</InstallDate>

    <LogicalProcessors>4</LogicalProcessors>

    <PhysicalProcessors>4</PhysicalProcessors>
  </Serverdata>
</PutColledtedData>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Perl Code:

```
use strict;
use SOAP::Lite trace =>  'debug', maptype => {};
use Sys::Hostname;

my $serverinfos={
OperatingSystem=>'',
OS_Version=>'',
OS_Architecture=>'',
OS_ServicePack=>'',
PysicalMemory=>'',
Manufacturer=>'',
Model=>'',
Hostname=>'',
Alias=>'',
WindowsDomain=>'',
WindowsDomainRole=>'',
InstallDate=>'',
LogicalProcessors=>'',
PhysicalProcessors=>'',
Interfaces=>'',
Filesystems=>'',

};
$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME}=0;
$SOAP::Constants::DO_NOT_USE_CHARSET = 1;


my $uri="http://tempuri.org/";
my $url ='https://myserver.her.de:1986/Webservice/Webservice.svc';
my $xmlns = 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/com.aii.observer';

my $soap = SOAP::Lite
  -> uri($uri)
  -> on_action(sub { sprintf '%sIObserverWebservice/%s', @_ })
  -> proxy($url, ssl_opts => [ SSL_verify_mode => 0 ] )
  ->autotype(0)
  ->readable('false');

 # some stuff to initialize the serverinfos Hash truncated


  my $param=SOAP::Data->name( "Serverdata"=>\SOAP::Data->value(
SOAP::Data->name(OperatingSystem=>''),
SOAP::Data->name(OS_Version=>$serverinfos->{OS_Version}),
SOAP::Data->name(OS_Architecture=>$serverinfos->{OS_Architecture}),
SOAP::Data->name(OS_ServicePack=>$serverinfos->{OS_ServicePack}),
SOAP::Data->name(PysicalMemory=>$serverinfos->{PysicalMemory}),
SOAP::Data->name(Manufacturer=>$serverinfos->{Manufacturer}),
SOAP::Data->name(Model=>''),
SOAP::Data->name(Hostname=>$serverinfos->{Hostname}),
SOAP::Data->name("Alias")->value($serverinfos->{Alias}),
SOAP::Data->name(WindowsDomain=>''),
SOAP::Data->name(WindowsDomainRole=>''),
SOAP::Data->name(InstallDate=>$serverinfos->{InstallDate}),
SOAP::Data->name(LogicalProcessors=>$serverinfos->{LogicalProcessors}),
SOAP::Data->name(PhysicalProcessors=>$serverinfos->{PhysicalProcessors})

)
);
my $res=$soap->call('PutColledtedData',$param);
```

in Webservice I get the Obekct for ServerInfoCollection but all Properties are null.

Where is my missunderstanding??

EDIT: 
Added Perl Code,
Added Webinvoke to ServiceInterface

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your Perl code. We can't tell you what is going wrong if we don't know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your perl code serverinfos values are empty. If filled, the server answer is ok.

Comment: Unfortunally no :( As You see in Saop Envelope the data for Object Serverdata is filled. Some strings are empty but this is normal behaviour.